# mathematical modeling and operational research

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I have a variable TE which  `0=<TE<=180`

Also, I have a parameters L(k) and U(K), showing lower bound and upper bound for interval `K` `(k=1,2,3)`

The value of these parameters are as follows:
`L(1)=0`  `K(1)=60` ,  `L(2)=60`   `K(2)=120`,  `L(3)=120`   `K(3)=180`

I need to find the related range of the variable TE.
For example,

```
  if `TE=12`,  then `K=1`

  if `TE=150`, then `k=3`
```

Which mathematical constraint(s) do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you prefer writing down your answer. Boolean logic is a perfectly valid way of writing mathematical expressions. For example, the logical "box" function, taking only the values 0 or 1 can be defined as follows:

$BOX(TE, L, U) = (TE > L)\; \& \;(TE < U)$

Then your entire choice can be written as

$k(TE) = 1 \cdot BOX(TE, L1, U1) + 2 \cdot BOX(TE, L2, U2) + 3 \cdot BOX(TE, L3, U3)$

which will always work as long as the intervals do not overlap. One can also use the step-function to define the box-function. Defining a piecewise function, as you did in the description is also mathematically perfectly valid. Take your pick